# removing entries by duplicate column

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

So I'm dealing with an odd issue in wordpress wherein I had a plugin creating duplicate entries in the database- and not realizing so- because wordpress was 'helping' by incrementing the post_id, enabling it to completely overlook all the other database values it should have simply overwritten. I've fixed the issue that created that, but I'm left with a very overfilled database with someting along the lines of 45,000 rows, many of which are just duplicates of the same data.

The database name is wp_postmeta with the columns meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value. I feel I need to just delete duplicate entries of the 'meta_value' column keeping the most recent 'post_id' of any duplicated value. I came up with this query after googling a bit and it seemed like it should do what I need it to do except that I get a version error below is the code and error:

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `meta_value` NOT IN (
    SELECT `meta_value` FROM wp_postmeta 
    GROUP BY `meta_value`
    ORDER BY `post_id` DESC
    LIMIT 1
);

#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

Now, I understand what this is saying, but am not quite familiar enough with working with sql to work around this with a different query that would essentially grab all duplicate 'meta_values' and delete the ones that are not the most recent 'post_id'. Could anyone point me in the right direction to look or help me out with a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

This might do it for you.  It should delete all but the row with the highest post_id.

```
DELETE oldposts.* FROM wp_postmeta oldposts
JOIN wp_postmeta newposts ON oldposts.meta_value = newposts.meta_value
   AND newposts.post_id > oldposts.post_id
```